# Combine IpWhitelist and Errors Middlewares. Is it possible?

Tags: traefik

I would like to do the following. Combine these two middlewares. If the user is not in the whitelist, then show an error page.

As far as I understand these 2 middlewares don't work together? Or can they be combined somehow? Didn't find anything in the documentation.

IpWhitelist works, but i become only text in Response, but I would like to get an error page.

```
................
      entryPoints:
        - websecure
      middlewares:
        - d-whitelist
        - service-errorpages
.................
```

and

```
middlewares:
    d-whitelist:
      ipWhiteList:
        sourceRange:
          - "95.95.95.95/32"
    service-errorpages:
      errors:
        status:
          - "401"
          - "403"
          - "404"
          - "500"
        service: tools
        query: "/{status}.html"
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

When defining middleware on a service, it is dependent on order within the array. If you flip `service-errorpages` and `d-whitelist` around, you will get a 403 response served from `service-errorpages` when requesting from a non-whitelisted IP.

If you have a lot of services using the same middleware (eg. both the whitelist & the error handler) with the same priority order, you may benefit from using [a chain](https://doc.traefik.io/traefik/middlewares/http/chain/).